# Does Windows 8 Have Limited Duration Licences?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

A family member bought a new laptop for personal use with Windows 8 preinstalled. It had been working without issues for the past two months or so, but has now started displaying warnings about its licence expiring in a month.

On the activation page it displays a key already entered, but I don't know anything about the key type. Pressing the activation button produces no feedback on whether the activation process failed or why.

What I want to know is whether there is such a thing as an activation key that grants a mere three months licence for Windows 8 - meaning we need to purchase a new, longer-lasting licence, or whether there could be some problem with the activation process.

Comment: What is the exact warning text?

Comment: run **slmgr.vbs /dlv** and post the output here.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, I call the Microsoft activation center.  It's not a painful process.

You should be able to reach the right phone number using these instructions :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929

Comment: My guess is something in the network is blocking activation and calling it in for a activation key would fix it.